# Nodejs connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: localhost, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, nginx, deployment, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I deloyed my Nodejs app to beanstalk service, I am able to Signup and Login my app, but after i Login, it just keeps buffering, not pulling any data, i checked my AWS logs and found this error

```
2021/10/22 23:43:09 [error] 3610#3610: *1 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: ip-address, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8080/", host: "ip-address"
```

i have changed my settings on my security groups in configuration with no luck, would be glad to get some assistance here. Thank you!

Comment: That looks like an error from nginx indicating your service has either failed to start or crashed.

Comment: What do you advice i do @jordanm so i restart the deployment process?